# overflow-x scroll not working css

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align two divs horizontally and I got it to work using `display:inline-block`
however when I put overlfow-x:scroll to the main container it doesn't work. If the screen is smaller, one of the div goes to the bottom. How can I achieve this? I don't want the second Div to go to the bottom if the screen is small.

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5HWD/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="test1">test1</div>
<div class="test2">test2</div>
</div>

.container{
display:table;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow-x:scroll;
}

.test1{
background-color:red;
 width:500px;
margin-left:16px;
display:inline-block;   


 }
.test2{
 margin-left:40px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:gray;
width:80px;

vertical-align:top;


}
```

Comment: Set fixed width to `container`

Comment: Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/f5HWD/1

Comment: I believe 636px is the exact width for `container` like Avin said

Answer (score 8, accepted):

give parameters to width and height, so container can overflow.

**http://jsfiddle.net/f5HWD/3**

```
.container{
    width: 900px;
    height: 700px;
    display:table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: @John: It is the general practice here on StackOverflow to not post an answer that has been suggested in the comments unless the OP asks the user to provide one because it was indeed the solution. MikelMax: If a user has provided a satisfactory answer in the comments ask *them* to give an answer so you can accept it. Taking points for another's answer is not encouraged

Comment: but this solution won't work when the screen size change? like if the page is opened on a cell phone.

Comment: @Martian2049 you can give percentage instead of pixel to achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/uh43p8cg/

Answer (score 1):

I altered your code slightly and made the contents `float left`.

In order you get it to work, you just had to create a wrapper class. You need the outside container to be large enough to just fit your test divs, while the wrapper is large enough to hold both combined. This should be fairly easy to figure out and edit according to the heights/widths that you want the divs to be.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MitulP91/eV8LT/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case display flex is working.